# Dragging Virtual Files Into Microsoft Office Communicator 2007

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, office-communicator

I've been trying to make an application that will allow me to drag files into an IM conversation window in Microsoft Office Communicator with no luck. I implemented / tried these two articles on creating virtual files for dragging:

1. [Transferring Virtual Files to Windows Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23139/Transferring-Virtual-Files-to-Windows-Explorer-in)
2. [Developer-Friendly Virtual File Implementation for .NET
   Improved!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/04/creating-something-from-nothing-asynchronously-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net-improved.aspx)

Both of these work great when I drag into Windows Explorer, but if I drag into an IM window it looks like it's going to work, i.e. it shows the file to transfer and the size etc... but when a person accepts it, it just hangs there until it fails with a message similar to this:

> Cannot send "Alphabet.txt" to LastName, FirstName. This may be due to firewall
>   restrictions or network problems. Please try again. If you need further 
>   assistance, contact your system administrator.

[image]

If I first drag the file into Windows Explorer and then from Explorer into the IM window it works fine. Anyone have any ideas of what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Microsoft Communicator expects the FileName & FileDrop data formats. If you supply those then it will work.